# UITextField doen not responding while click?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I have a UIImageview, which covers entire View of the main VC, then I have added a UIView on the imageView, Then I have added two UITextFields in the view, as in the image below.

[image]

Now,

- I have marked ImageView, innerView and both the textField's isUserInteractionEnable as true
- I have also `self.view.bringSubviewToFront(phoneNumberTextField)`

But still when I try to click on TextField it does not response,

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.view.bringSubviewToFront(phoneNumberTextFieldOutlet)
    self.phoneNumberTextFieldOutlet.becomeFirstResponder()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}


@objc func textFieldDidChange(textField: UITextField){
    let text = textField.text
    if text?.utf16.count ?? 0 == 10{
        self.mobileNumber = text ?? "0"
        passwordTextFieldOutlet.becomeFirstResponder()
    }else{
        //Do nothing
    }
}

@IBOutlet weak var passwordTextFieldOutlet: UITextField!{
    didSet{
        passwordTextFieldOutlet.onlyBottomBorder()
    }
}
@IBOutlet weak var phoneNumberTextFieldOutlet: UITextField!{
    didSet{
        phoneNumberTextFieldOutlet.onlyBottomBorder()
        phoneNumberTextFieldOutlet.delegate = self
        phoneNumberTextFieldOutlet.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidChange), for: UIControl.Event.editingChanged)
        phoneNumberTextFieldOutlet.addTarget(self, action: #selector(phoneNumberFieldTouched), for: .touchDown)
    }
}




func resetAllFields(){
    self.phoneNumberTextFieldOutlet.text = nil
    self.passwordTextFieldOutlet.text = nil
    self.phoneNumberTextFieldOutlet.becomeFirstResponder()
}

func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    if textField.tag == 1{
        let aSet = NSCharacterSet(charactersIn:"0123456789").inverted
        let compSepByCharInSet = string.components(separatedBy: aSet)
        let numberFiltered = compSepByCharInSet.joined(separator: "")
        return string == numberFiltered
    }
    return true
}

@objc func phoneNumberFieldTouched(){
    self.phoneNumberTextFieldOutlet.becomeFirstResponder()
}
```

After Debugging I got this,
[image: Views Hierarchy]

Below is the screen short from storyboard,
[image: StoryBoard screen short]

Comment: Can you please share your code here so I can review and find the solution.

Comment: Hi @ChiragKalsariya I have added code

Comment: you must set userInteractionEnable property value to true for the Imageview.

Comment: @vivekDas, I have set this already in storyboard, but does not worked for me!

Comment: don't make userInteractionEnable true for all the elements okay, only imageview's userInteractionEnable should set to true.

Comment: And what about Both the textFields?

Comment: It still won't work

Comment: @shubhammishra - give your `UIView` that holds the text fields a background color, so we can see its frame. Also, would help if you show a screen-cap of your view in your Storyboard.

Comment: @DonMag, added storyboard screen short

Comment: @shubhammishra - expand the constraints so we can see the actual layout... If you cannot even tap into a text field to give it the focus, it sounds like its superview is not sizing as you expect it to. On your view containing the text fields, give it a background color and set `.clipsToBounds = true` to see its frame at run-time.

Comment: Please explain what are you trying to do in `shouldChangeCharactersIn` method.

Comment: @shubhammishra - Does Storyboard show any constraint issues (yellow or red icon)? Can you re-capture your screen so we can see the full constraint values (stretch the Document Outline pane wider)? Can you show how this looks at runtime (with the gray background)?

Comment: The height constraints for the grey view was missing, but I Added it, then also issue persists.

Comment: @shubhammishra - it sounds like you still may have constraint issues. If you post the source for your storyboard (either in your answer or a pastebin), I will take a look at it.

Comment: All UIView userInteractionEnable properties set to true. The super view must be userInteractionEnable true, please check the main view properties also.

Comment: Finally, got the task done. @DonMag u was correct their was the constraint issue. For the InnerView (Login's UIView) their were only leading, trailing and top constraints present, but then when I gave it the Height constraint then soon the TextEdit view started responding. Thanks to all friends for your inputs.

Answer (score 0):

I could not see delegation of UITextField in your code. I assume you should  extend UITextFieldDelegate like below. And also, giving sender info selector functions is a better options for coding.

```
UITextFieldDelegate

Class SomeClass : UITextFieldDelegate {

func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    // to do
}
```

}

```
@objc func textFieldChanged(_ sender : UITextField) {

    // to do

}
```

Comment: I tried it, it is working fine but for that I have to call .becomeFirstResponder(), purposely in viewDidLoad(), then it allows me to edit the textEdit field, but after taking phone Number I am making passwordTextEdit as FirstResponser(), But then when I am trying to click on phoneTextEditor it does not work

Comment: I assume that you don't have to set firstResponder when you next enter some text on passwordText field. Because firstresponder works for opening keyboard. Keyboard already opened in your case when your viewDidLoad. You should call becomeFirstResponder once.